# calculate the work done bay the field $ \vec{F} $ to move a particle along the parabolic arc $y=x^{2}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Where $x$ ranges from $0$ to $1$ for $F(x,y) = \dfrac{1}{1+x^{2}} \; \vec{j}$

Comment: Can you think of an integral relating work and force? Look at the 'work (physics)' wiki and you will definitely find out how to proceed.

Comment: Young man, I did not ask the question. I'm just trying to understand and / or find a way to solve. I followed your concern and continue with the same problem. If you can not help me, thank you anyway.

Comment: $$\int_C{\frac{dy}{1+x^2}}=\int_0^1{\frac{2xdx}{1+x^2}}=\ln(1+x^2)|_0^1=\ln2$$

Comment: @Daniil Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your curve is given by $c(t)=(t,t^2)$  for $t \in [0,1]$. Then you have to compute

$\int_{c}F(x,y)*d(x,y)=\int_{0}^1 F(c(t)) *c'(t)dt$.

Your turn !

Comment: Mm... I'll try here and see if I can get the result.